# Angular 4 retrieve number which is returned by a get call

Tags: angular, typescript, get

I have my spring-boot back-end app in which I have written my query as follows:

```
@Query("SELECT COUNT(*) "
            + "FROM Foo "
            + "WHERE name = :name and surname = :surname ")
Integer countByNameAndSurname(@Param("name") String name, @Param("surname") String surname);
```

The query and my back-end side works as I desire. On my front-end side which is built using Angular 4, I am not able to retrieve the pure integer I am returning from the back-end. Whatever I tried, I couldn't resolve it.

```
getCount() {
     return this.http.get(this.actionUrl + this.param,{headers: DataService.getHeaders()})
      .subscribe(response => {
          console.log(response);
          console.log(response.json());
          this.countResult = response.json();
        //return this.countResult;
          return response.json();
        })
  }
```

(I tried also giving it a return value as `getCount(): number{...}` and returned the variable `countResult` that I assign inside the call, but no success.)
This is the method inside my service class. I tried both to assign it into a public variable `this.countResult` and try to reach it from another class, and also returning the `response.json()._body;` which is the pure integer I need. I guarantee the call is being done perfectly right. I have tested it more than once.

Yet I always get the Subscriber object which inside contains a big nothing. [image: subscriber obj]

I call the service as follows:

```
var count = this.dataService.getCountExternalCvs();
console.log(count);
```

And when I print the `count`, it's the subscriber obj as above.

I had to use `.subscribe()` because I do not want the response to be a Promise, I need the value as it is.

Here is the response and response.json() I print in my service call, and the subscriber object where I get by `var count = this.dataService.getCountExternalCvs();`
[image: response-response.json()-subscriber]

Whatever I tried, I couldn't get rid of the Subscriber obj and retrieve the true response.

Comment: The service must NOT subscribe. It must return an Observable. The component, calling the service, is the one which subscribes and sets its state when the event is emitted. You can't transform an asynchronous call into a synchronous one. It's plain impossible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return Observable as below from the service

```
getCount():Observable<any> {
//service code with MAP to return the json object
   }
```

In your component class, call a method

```
getCountFromService(){
service.getCount().subscribe((data)=>this.countResult =data)
}
```

and use countResult in HTML markup to display the count.